# Two main functions when using a floating action button

Tags: buttons, call-to-action, material-design

We are designing a complex app with a lot of different pages/views. From all of the pages we want to be able to "Add" stuff that is relevant to the whole instance. Most times this means you add things to the view you are in, but not exclusively (it can at the same time add things to the other views, or only to other views).

We are mainly designing according to Google's Material design and have right now solved this with a [floating action button](http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button) (FAB), that is available on all pages.

So to our problem; from one of the pages we have a different "Main" function. We still want to be able to Add, and therefore I still have the FAB visible. But how should we display the other function?
It feels strange to change the FAB since we still want to be able to use the Add-function, but it also feels strange to have a FAB when another function is "more main". Also, it feels strange to add another FAB since Google clearly states there should be only one.

Comment: FAB? I must be out of the loop.

Comment: FAB! Thunderbirds are go!

Answer (score 3):

If the "more main" functions are all related to adding things, you could have the FAB expand into a collection of smaller FABs that give more options. Tapping on the original FAB a second time could execute your primary action. Google's *Inbox* app demonstrates this, as do apps like Tumblr.

[image]

Alternatively, you could change the icon on the FAB to be something more generic and not constrain yourself to just adding things, though that feels like cheating the purpose of the FAB.